# Draw on top of an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, canvas

For a certain image I have a list containing the pixel coordinates of all the points in a polygon segmenting all the objects it contains (look at the image below).

For instance, for the person I have a list `l1 = [x0,y0,x1,y1,...,xn,yn]`, for the cat a list `l2 = [x0',y0',x1',y1',...,xk',yk']`, and similarly for all the objects.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the best `javascript` library to use to draw on top of an image? Given the raw image I would like to obtain the result seen below.
2. I would like each segmentation to be visualized only when the mouse hovers on top of it. For this I believe I should bind this drawing function to the mouse position.

I'm thinking at something with the structure below but don't know how to fill the gaps, could you please give me some indication?

```
$(.container).hover( function(e) {
    //get coordinates of mouse
    //if mouse is over one object
    //draw on top of image the segmentation for that object
});
```

`container` is the class of the div containing the image so I should be able to get the coordinates of the mouse since the image starts at the top left corner of the `container` div.

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: I would look at the ImageMapster plugin; it's jQuery-based (which I know you didn't say or tag your question as, but your example script is jQ) and it supports the use cases you describe. http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

Comment: Both SVG and Canvas can map non-rectangular paths and display text upon hovering over those paths. Since SVG is a full-fledged DOM element, you can ask each non-rectangular SVG element to react upon hovering.  Canvas allows you to hit-test non-rectangular paths with `context.isPointInPath`.  If your design need doesn't go beyond displaying with text upon hovering a non-rectangular path, I would go with SVG because it interacts with the user out-of-the-box.

Comment: @AlexWeinstein - no...

Comment: @Stevangelista - It might be a bit late, but that is a great pointer. Thanks! Do you have any advice on how to use those demos to answer this question?

Answer (score 4):

Simply rebuild the polygons from each array and do a hit test using the mouse position.

First: If you have many arrays defining the shapes it could be smarter to approach it in a more general way instead of using variables for each array as this can soon be hard to maintain. Better yet, an object holding the array and for example id could be better.

Using an object you could do - example:

```
function Shape(id, points, color) {
    this.id = id;
    this.points = points;
    this.color = color;
}

// this will build the path for this shape and do hit-testing:
Shape.prototype.hitTest = function(ctx, x, y) {
    ctx.beginPath();

    // start point
    ctx.moveTo(this.points[0], this.points[1]);

    // build path
    for(var i = 2, l = this.points.length; i < l; i += 2) {
        ctx.lineTo(this.points[i], this.points[i+1]);
    }

    ctx.closePath();

    return ctx.isPointInPath(x, y);
};
```

Now you can create new instances with the various point arrays like this:

```
var shapes = [];

shapes.push(new Shape("Cat", [x0,y0,x1,y1, ...], "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)");
shapes.push(new Shape("Woman", [x0,y0,x1,y1, ...], "rgba(0,255,0,0.5)"));
...
```

When you get a mouse position simply hit-test each shape:

```
$(".container").hover( function(e) {
    //get corrected coordinates of mouse to x/y
    // redraw canvas without shapes highlighted

    for(var i = 0, shape; shape = shapes[i]; i++) { // get a shape from array
        if (shape.hitTest(ctx, x, y)) {             // is x/y inside shape?
            ctx.fillStyle = shape.color;            // we already have a path
            ctx.fill();                             // when testing so just fill
            // other tasks here...
            break;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a few clarifications, what exactly is `ctx`? Is it a library or a variable as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994046/why-do-all-canvas-examples-use-ctx) example? And also, do I need to use a some sort of `canvas` element in order to draw on the image or can I just do it on top of the `container`?

Comment: @Matteo yes, `ctx` is as of that link (the canvas context). You will need a canvas element to draw in (if you don't choose to go with SVG). There are many examples on this site on how to setup and use the canvas element itself. I would recommend looking into those if you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

check this [Link](http://ianli.com/sketchpad/) it might be slow your problem.

**Include necessary javascript library files**
jquery.min.js,raphael.min.js,json2.min.js,raphael.sketchpad.js

**To create an editor**

```
<div id="editor"></div>
   <form action="save.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="data" />
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sketchpad = Raphael.sketchpad("editor", {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    editing: true
});
// When the sketchpad changes, update the input field.
  sketchpad.change(function() {
  $("#data").val(sketchpad.json());
  });
</script>
```